# Response must have 3 or more levels

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to perform a ordinal logistic regression using R, but I keep getting this error which says: response must have 3 or more levels. What does "response" mean in R? Tried searching on google but nothing is explained on the meaning of response in R. I am pasting the snapshot of the data I am trying to regress and the code I have written so far:

[image]

```
m <- polr(as.factor(Gender) ~ VeryUnsat + Unsat + Sat + VerySat, data = df, Hess=TRUE)
summary(m)
ctable <- coef(summary(m))
p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p)
ci <- confint(m)
exp(coef(m))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(m), ci))`
```

Comment: "Response" is the outcome you're trying to model. Right now it looks like you have your formula backwards, as the response/outcome should be on the left-hand side of `~`, where you currently have `Gender`.

Comment: So how do I fix this? Age has 3 levels, but not gender...

Comment: Pls provide data, no pictures. Check `?dput`.

Comment: I am new to this community, how do I provide my data here? It is in an excel file..

Comment: What are you trying to model here? It looks like your response/outcome should be satisfaction, which has 4 levels. You need something like `polr(Satisfaction ~ age + gender + other_predictors)`, but you may have to reshape your data so it's "long" and you have one row per observation first.

Comment: read your data in R using `read.csv' and save it for instance yourdf=read.csv("path to excel file.csv") or use `readxl::read_excel("path to file")` Then use `dput(yourdf)` and paste the output here

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the example of polr method.
Just type ?polr in your command line in RStudio

You will see that your response variable is not well defined for what polr expects (unless I am misunderstanding what you try to do)

polr tries to model multilevel ordered variables such as Sat in the example.

I see two problems in your data:

1. you have aggregated data, a count of how many samples have each level of satisfaction for each combination of age and gender.
2. your response variable is splitted across different columns. Starting from the non-aggregated data you need to convert to a single variable with multiple possible values (VeryUnsat, Unsat, Sat, VerySat)

You may be able to use the aggregated data if the method allows to specify some weights to each combination (haven't checked the details of the method).